# ASP.NET webservice not found in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to create a web service in Visual Studio 2019 using C# and .NET, but I could not find option of web service - neither in ASP.NET Core nor the .NET framework. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Which .net framework? [Refer This link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152102.aspx?Web+Service+ASMX+Not+Available+in+Visual+Studio+when+use+Net+Framework+4+6+2)

Comment: [That could help you.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b75f659-521e-4e08-b093-11d7bfb63ef1/missing-web-templates-for-c-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=netfxsetup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a simple web service using this template:

**Step-1:** In Visual Studio, create a new project using the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) template, and select the Empty template when prompted. Type a name and create the project.

**Step-2:** In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node, choose Add > New Item, and then choose Web Service (ASMX). Add the web service.

**Step-3:** Open WebService1.asmx and replace the default HelloWorld web method with the following code.

```
public string HelloWorld(string str)
{
  return "Hello, " + str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not getting option for Webservice

Comment: Can You please let me know about vs 2019 asp.net web service?

Answer (score 0):

Its likely you have chosen .net core as project type when creating the project. You need to choose Web applications. Check the image below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the project name and hit ADD, go down to Service Reference and choose web service

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).